# Why does "\n" in a swift string behave differently in slightly different situations?

Tags: swift, string

I have a custom keyboard extension that inputs data from a BLE device into a text field.

```
func getdata(data:Data){
...
processing data from BLE device
...
dataToSend = "...\n"
textDocumentProxy.insertText(dataToSend)
}
```

When this function is used to insert text in different applications it behaves differently. For example, in notes, the line feed ("\n") seems to work correctly and insert a new line. But when the data is being inserted in an email or a numbers sheet, it does not work correctly and instead of inserting a new line, it inserts a tab ("\t").

I also have a function that inserts a new line character

```
func newLine(){
textDocumentProxy.insertText("\n")
}
```

that works as expected regardless of what application I am using. Does anyone know why "\n" by itself works correctly but when at the end of a string has different behavior?

For completeness, I have tried calling newLine() at the end of getdata() thinking there may be an issue with inserting "\n" at the end of a string but the results were the same.

Answer (score 0):

There are another newLine characters available but I can't just simply paste them here (Because they make a new lines).

using this extension:

```
extension CharacterSet {
    var allCharacters: [Character] {
        var result: [Character] = []
        for plane: UInt8 in 0...16 where self.hasMember(inPlane: plane) {
            for unicode in UInt32(plane) << 16 ..< UInt32(plane + 1) << 16 {
                if let uniChar = UnicodeScalar(unicode), self.contains(uniChar) {
                    result.append(Character(uniChar))
                }
            }
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

you can access all characters in any `CharacterSet`. There is a character set called `newlines`. Use one of them to fulfill your requirements:

```
let newlines = CharacterSet.newlines.allCharacters
for newLine in newlines {
    textDocumentProxy.insertText(String(newLine))
}
```

Then store the one you tested and worked everywhere and use it anywhere.
Note that you can't relay on the index of the character set. It may change.

Comment: You can actually just look up the characters in newlines. The comment above newlines in the definition is: Returns a character set containing the newline characters (`U+000A ~ U+000D`, `U+0085`, `U+2028`, and `U+2029`).

Comment: Perfect! Use one of them then

Comment: These different characters did not solve my problem. My issue is not that I can't enter a new line, it's that the newline characters behave different depending on where they are entered from: i.e. by pressing a button or entering at the end of a string.

Comment: Of course some of them could have *delegate* methods to handle *return* and you can’t change them. But you can return something different than *return* to get around it.